# Error in executing jest test cases for nodejs application with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules, ts-jest

When I run jest test cases for nodejs application. I am facing this error after tests execution succeed.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xx-yy-zz/backend/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/src/index.ts’

However this error doesn’t come on my local system. This file doesn;t exist neither on local system nor on jenkin workspace but still it give this error. I am not getting the reason. Due to which coverage folder is not generated on jenkin workspace however on local it works.

This is my jest.config.js

```
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
preset: ‘ts-jest’,
testEnvironment: ‘node’,
verbose: true,
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [ “\\node_modules\\”],
coverageProvider: “v8”,
testMatch: [‘/tests//.ts?(x)', '**/?(.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)’],
setupFilesAfterEnv: [‘./jest.setup.ts’],
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: “/coverage”,
}
export default config;
```

Not able to find the reason for this issue.